# Jest, expect another asynchronous callback not to be called

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs

I am using Jest framework for testing, I know that I have to call `done()` function, whenever asynchronous testing is finished, like this

```
it("should be executed", (done)=>{

    const callback = jest.fun(()=>{
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    })    

    someFakeStream$.subscribe(callback);
})
```

Now I have the following scenario, I want to ensure that my callback only fires once, even if the event fires multiple times, so I have

```
it("should be executed", (done)=>{

    //I Want to ensure that this function invoces only once
    const callback = jest.fun(()=>{
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    })    

    someFakeStream$.subscribe(callback);

    someFakeStream$.next();
    someFakeStream$.next();
})
```

now If I leave the callback code as same as it is it will not work, because done function will be called after the first emission, I could add the fail condition on this method

```
 const callback = jest.fun(()=>{
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
        if (callback.mock.calls.length > 1) { // This will call fail if it's invoked twice
        done.fail();
      }
    })
```

but now I don't have `done()` method called, so I will have jest timeout exception.
how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you really need an asynchronous test here. If the stream is in fact a Subject then the `next` call will directly invoke the subscribe callback. So first, I'd remove the `done` callback altogether.

The expect also looks a bit off. Generally you'd want to place the expectation after the "acting" (when following an arrange/act/assert model). So I guess your code could work like this:

```
describe('test', () => {
    it('should be executed', () => {
        const callback = jest.fn();

        someFakeStream$.subscribe(callback);

        someFakeStream$.next();
        someFakeStream$.next();

        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Not sure how you'd achieve that your callback is only called once with the above stream though.

If you really need async testing (for timeouts, intervals or Promises), then install a fake timer before your test:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
```

and put this before your expect:

```
...
jest.runAllTimers();
expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: I was using https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter  not Subject for emitting, so it emitted values asynchronously. but your solution worked anyway runAllTimers() fixed an issue for thanks in advance :)